# Odata type conversion for numeric types

Tags: entity-framework-6, odata

I have this base class for my entities

```
public abstract class BaseEntity : IEntity, IAuditable
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and two ODATA endpoint inheriting EntityFrameworkDataService.

My first service is using EDMX generated using visual studio designer and on the browser Id property is serialized as numeric type as you might expect.

for the 2nd endpoint i decided to drop EDMX and use fluent configuration however this time Id property on the browser is serialized as string.

Why this happens? Is there additional configuration needed to tell the runtime that i want my long types to be serialized as numeric in json?

Comment: Please post the fluent config code for some entity class that derives from BaseEntity. And the corresponding CSDL from your $metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Id` is `long` type. for `long` value, it follows up the odata spec to serialize to JSON:

---

OData [spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.0/errata02/os/odata-json-format-v4.0-errata02-os-complete.html#_Controlling_the_Representation) says:

*The IEEE754Compatible=true format parameter indicates that the service MUST serialize **Edm.Int64** (long) and **Edm.Decimal** (decimal) numbers (including the odata.count, if requested) as **strings**. This is in conformance with [I-JSON](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.0/errata02/os/odata-json-format-v4.0-errata02-os-complete.html#ijson).*

*If not specified, or specified as IEEE754Compatible=false, all numbers MUST be serialized as JSON numbers.*

---